# Text on a image

Tags: php, image, text

Is it possible to dynamically place text on an image in php?
And then send it to an rss feed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, can use either the [GD](http://www.php.net/gd) functions or the [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/imagemagick) functions, depending on which is installed on your server and which you prefer.

Using GD it would go something like this:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('my.jpg');
$textColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); // black text

imagefttext($img, 13, 0, 105, 55, $textColor, './arial.ttf', 'Hello World');

// Output image to the browser
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);

// Or save to file
imagejpeg($img, 'my-text.jpg');

imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Edit:

To put the image into your RSS feed you would save it to a file and put the URL into your feed.

Comment: Can I also send this image then in an rss feed?

Answer (score 3):

Of course. With [`imagefttext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) from GD. You'll need TTF files though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GD with the [imagecreatefromjpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) (or any other format), and then [imageftttext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) to draw the string.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some ImageMagick libraries for PHP](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php). Once you have that installed, you might [annotate](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/) your image with relevant PHP'ed ImageMagick commands.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to cache that file in some way. Since both GD and Imagick are heavy on the server and can take some time to create.