# get base64 php string into img tag

Tags: php, html, base64

Ive got a php file 'get.php' that echo's a base64 string.

How would i display this as an image in another .php page?

something like this:

```
<img src="get.php?id=$lastid">
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: This won't work unless that page is returning an image and not just a string representation of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64STRING">
```

but if you BASE64STRING is the output of a php, then something like this would work:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php include 'get.php?id=$lastid' ?>>
```

I know it may not be exactly but I hope you get the idea

Comment: Wouldn't this cause some kind of compatibility problem? that doesn't seem too friendly...

Comment: yes, some browsers may not support it, anyway it is 'standard', it is just another solution, but I prefer that the PHP directly outputs the image, like the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display that as an image you will need to look into GD Library and generate a run time image using a function like `imagettftext()` after the image has been generated, your PHP script will send a header saying this is an image something like

```
header( "Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

and then echo the binary data of the generate image.

I found this question for you which should help you get started, look at the accepted answer:
[Text on a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688913/text-on-a-image)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to echo the output of `get.php` directly. Why don't you just include and call that function on the original page in source? Don't forget that the base64 string needs `data:image/png;base64,` or similar at the beginning.

```
<?php

include_once('get.php');

echo '<img src="'.base64img($lastid).'">';
```