# How would I get a dynamically generated PHP image to display on a webpage after creation?

Tags: php, gd

Okay, my problem here is I want to display the dynamically generated images on a webpage after they have been generated and provide a link for the user to use the image. When I try to echo the image:

```
echo '<img src="link/sig.php?username='.$_GET['username'].'&fakeparm=.png />';
```

The webpage displays the image fine, but with the addition of a million weird characters. Below is the image creation snippet.

```
$image_link = 'image.png';
$image = imagecreatefrompng($image_link);

$font_colour = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$font_size = 3; 

$x = array('28', '80', '135', '188', '240'); 
$y = array('8', '29', '52', '77', '100'); 

$i = '0';
$a = '0';
foreach($stat as $s_key => $value){
    imagestring($image, $font_size, $x[$a], $y[$i], $value[1], $font_colour);
     $i++;
if($i == '5'){
    $i = '0';
    $a++;
}
}

imagestring($image, $font_size, '230', '100', 'Total:'. $overall[1], $font_colour);
imagestring($image, $font_size, '240', '75', '' . $username, $font_colour);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Value of `$stat`.

```
$stats = explode("\n", $website);
$overall = explode(",", $stats[0]);
$stat['att'] = explode(",", $stats[1]);
$stat['def'] = explode(",", $stats[2]);
$stat['str'] = explode(",", $stats[3]);
$stat['hp'] = explode(",", $stats[4]);
$stat['rng'] = explode(",", $stats[5]);
$stat['pry'] = explode(",", $stats[6]);
$stat['mag'] = explode(",", $stats[7]);
$stat['ck'] = explode(",", $stats[8]);
$stat['wc'] = explode(",", $stats[9]);
$stat['flt'] = explode(",", $stats[10]);
$stat['fsh'] = explode(",", $stats[11]);
$stat['fm'] = explode(",", $stats[12]);
$stat['cra'] = explode(",", $stats[13]);
$stat['smi'] = explode(",", $stats[14]);
$stat['min'] = explode(",", $stats[15]);
$stat['her'] = explode(",", $stats[16]);
$stat['ag'] = explode(",", $stats[17]);
$stat['th'] = explode(",", $stats[18]);
$stat['sl'] = explode(",", $stats[19]);
$stat['frm'] = explode(",", $stats[20]);
$stat['rc'] = explode(",", $stats[21]);
$stat['hun'] = explode(",", $stats[22]);
$stat['cs'] = explode(",", $stats[23]);
```

**Note: Image is generated fine, everything works... I want to display the generated image on a webpage instead of being forwarded to the image itself...**

Comment: are you closing the `img` tag?

Comment: @Raidenace Yes, I am.

Comment: What do you mean by "a million weird characters"? And how do you know that the image itself is being correctly generated?

Comment: ok, I see you have updated the question...so next question - what is the value of `$stat`?

Comment: @Raidenace Post updated with the `$stats` variable.

Comment: @vcardillo Because the image displays fine with this code: `header('Content-type: image/png');`. What I want to do is display the dynamically generated image on a webpage instead of the way it is displayed currently. As for the symbols please refer to this link: http://gyazo.com/22a628b54c9aa0326395beb7fcc48bca

Comment: @CoryAllen: All I can say is that there should be issues with that variable so you have to backtrace where the issue is. The code you pasted seems perfectly ok. To test that theory, try putting this line `$stat = array("1"=>"a","2"=>"b","3"=>"c");`just before the `foreach` and check if the image gets displayed

Comment: @CoryAllen Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964323/get-base64-php-string-into-img-tag `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ..." />` instead of linking to the php script that serves the image?

Answer (score 1):

You have not closing the img tag...

```
 echo '<img src="link/sig.php?username='.$_GET['username'].'&fakeparm=.png" />';
```

instead of

```
 echo '<img src="link/sig.php?username='.$_GET['username'].'&fakeparm=.png />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no characters or browser output before you declare your headers. Not even spaces.
Otherwise the browser may try and read the image as html giving you your "million weird characters".

Comment: I have solved my issue. Instead of having my form redirect directly to the heart of the image generator I needed to direct it to a page with an image tag with the $_GET variable and my image tag, for example: `sigdone.php?username='.$_GET['username'].'`