# Manipulating images with PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to add additional information to an image.

What I want to do is:

1. Add a 300px wide by 40px high flat colour banner flush with the bottom left edge of the image.
2. Add image text on top of this banner

Basically, I want to mark the image with a shape and text.

Are there any PHP Libraries or built-in PHP functionality I would need to get this done?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add text on top of an image through CSS. Why php specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688913/text-on-a-image

Comment: Because I want to make the edit permanent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) extension and [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension support these functions via their `imagefttext()` and `Imagick::annotateImage()` functions, respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will explore this further. Cheers.